# convert date to continuous variable in R

Tags: r, date

How can I convert date to continuous variable staring from 1. I tried as.numeric but R starts counting from default January 1, 1970 while my data start Oct 7, 2009.

I need to do this conversion to plot the date on two x-axes (1 and 3).

```
plot(LAI~Date, data=LAI_simulation)
LAI_simulation$Date<- as.numeric(LAI_simulation$Date,origin="2009-10-07")
#R does not see the origin
axis.Date(side=3,at=LAI_simulation$Date)
# also tried seq
dates <- seq(LAI_simulation$Date[1, "2009-10-07"], LAI_simulation$Date[nrow(LAI_simulation$Date), "2010-10-07"], by = "days")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just subtract the base date and then transform like `LAIsimulation$index <- as.integer(LAI_simulation$Date - as.Date("2009-10-06"))`.

Comment: Thanks worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
LAI_simulation$Date <- as.Date( LAI_simulation$Date, '%Y/%m/%d')
LAI_simulation$Date <- as.integer(LAI_simulation$Date - as.Date("2009-10-07"))
plot(LAI~Date,data=LAI_simulation,xlab="Days since Oct, 7, 2009",cex=0.3,cex.lab=1.2,xaxt="n",xaxs="i",yaxs="i",ylim=c(0,6))
axis(1,xlim=c(0,2200),xaxp=c(0,2200,11),cex.lab=1.2,cex.axis=0.8,xaxs="i")
LAI_simulation$Date<- as.Date(LAI_simulation$Date, origin="2009-10-07") 
par(new=TRUE)
plot(LAI~Date, data=LAI_simulation,xlab="",ylab="",
     xaxt="n",type="p",cex=0.2,col=1,xaxs="i",yaxs="i",ylim=c(0,6))
axis.Date(side=3, at=seq(min(LAI_simulation$Date), max(LAI_simulation$Date),by="year"), format="%Y", xlab="xxx",cex.axis=0.9)
mtext("years",side=3,line=3,cex.lab=1.2)
```